# Diagonal separator in table corner in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context

How can one create a diagonal separator in a table corner in ConTeXt (like the package slashbox for LaTeX)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [natural tables](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE):

```
\startuseMPgraphic{DiagonalRule}
draw (0,OverlayHeight) -- (OverlayWidth,0);
clip currentpicture to OverlayBox; % otherwise the rule overlaps the table frame
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [DiagRule]
  [\useMPgraphic{DiagonalRule}]

\setupTABLE [1] [1] [background=DiagRule]

\starttext
\bTABLE
\bTR \bTD   \eTD   \bTD col   \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD row \eTD \bTD value \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

The nice thing about natural tables is that the background of a cell can be just about anything. In this case, I am using a simple metapost graphic that draws a diagonal line.

Comment: There is an anonymous edit suggestion for this answer which states to add `clip currentpicture to OverlayBox;` just before `\stopuseMPgraphic` because "otherwise the rule overlaps the table frame". Instead if approving it I add it here as comment so you can decide it for yourself.

Comment: @martin: yes, that makes sense, will edit

Comment: thanks, that's nice. Is it possible to add headings to be separated by the diagonal too? Like having row\col in in top left table corner only.