# ConTeXt: Add a proportionality arrow to a table

Tags: context

I am trying to generate proportionality tables, like this one:

[image]

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12378/213111) I know it is possible to change background of a cell, so I tried to change the background of the last column. The following code shows as far as I could go

```tex
\startuseMPgraphic{TableArrow}
  path p ; p := halfcircle scaled OverlayHeight ;
  drawarrow reverse(p) ;
  clip currentpicture to OverlayBox;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[TableArrow][\useMPgraphic{TableArrow}]

\starttext
  \bTABLE
  \setupTABLE[last][first][background=TableArrow]
  \setupTABLE[c][each][width=0.150\textwidth]
  \bTABLEbody
  \bTR\bTD Number of Bottles \eTD
      \bTD $2$ \eTD
      \bTD $3$ \eTD
      \bTD $4$ \eTD
      \bTD $\cdots$ \eTD
      \bTD $x$ \eTD
      \bTD[nr=2]\eTD\eTR
  \bTR\bTD Price (\$)\eTD
      \bTD $2.40$ \eTD
      \bTD $3.60$ \eTD
      \bTD $4.80$ \eTD
      \bTD $\cdots$ \eTD
      \bTD $y$ \eTD\eTR
  \eTABLEbody
  \eTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

but I could not make it.

When I shifted the path it "disappears". How can I start and end the arrow on the edges of previous cells?
And, a bit strange, why when I scaled the `halfcircle` with `OverlayHeight/2` it does not work? Anyway I probably should use something else than `halfcircle` but I do not know what exactly.

Subsidiary question. How can I act on penultimate cells with `\setupTABLE`? I tried `\setupTABLE[row][last-1][]` but I does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clipping, you can set the width of the last column in the table to zero, and play with the bounding box of the MetaFun graphic. I also changed some parameters in the table to make it look more as in the picture you attached. The 3pt in the x-coordinates in the path p correspond to the offset between the table and the arrow.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{TableArrow}
  path p ; p := (3pt,0.9OverlayHeight){dir -50} .. {dir -130}(3pt,0.1OverlayHeight) ;
  drawarrow p ;
  label.rt("\im{\times} \$1.20/bottle", point 0.5 along p) ;
  setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xyscaled (OverlayWidth,OverlayHeight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[TableArrow][\useMPgraphic{TableArrow}]

\starttext
  \bTABLE
  \setupTABLE[last][first][background=TableArrow]
  \setupTABLE[c][each][width=0.150\textwidth,align={middle,lohi},height=8ex]
  \setupTABLE[c][last][width=0dk]
  \bTABLEbody
  \bTR\bTD Number of Bottles \eTD
      \bTD $2$ \eTD
      \bTD $3$ \eTD
      \bTD $4$ \eTD
      \bTD $\cdots$ \eTD
      \bTD $x$ \eTD
      \bTD[nr=2]\eTD\eTR
  \bTR\bTD Price (\$)\eTD
      \bTD $2.40$ \eTD
      \bTD $3.60$ \eTD
      \bTD $4.80$ \eTD
      \bTD $\cdots$ \eTD
      \bTD $y$ \eTD\eTR
  \eTABLEbody
  \eTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image: the resulting table]

Comment: Perfect ! One last question. I tried to look at the documentation but I could not find a thing. Is there an easy way to change the label or should I create an overlay for each one?

Comment: I guess you can use some `\MPvar` or something similar. I would look in the MetaFun manual.

Comment: `0dk` :-) I didn’t expect to see dk units _in the wild_

Comment: It is in fact a convenient length. For making small examples, `\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]` has become standard for me. (But OK, the `0dk` was perhaps not necessary.)